# Listing Objects in GCS Bucket Asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, google-cloud-storage

I would like to execute several requests to GCS for listing objects in specific bucket, at the same time, and collect all the results.
Every request has different prefix.

Currently all the requests run one by one:

```
for prefix in prefix_list:      
    request = gcs_service.objects().list(bucket=bucket,prefix=prefix,delimiter='/')
    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        for item in response['prefixes']:
            organizations.add(item)
        request = gcs_service.objects().list_next(request, response)
```

How can I save time and run all requests asynchronously? (simultaneously)